# How do I keep a background image bullet aligned with the first line of a wrapped list item?

Tags: html, css, background-image, bulletedlist

I am using background images as bullets.

```
ul.follow-background li.facebookicon {
        list-style:none outside !important;
        background: url('/wp-content/uploads/facebook-icon-16x16.png') no-repeat left 50%;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin: 0.3em 0 0 -0.7em;
        padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
    }

ul.follow-background li.twittericon {
    list-style:none outside !important;
    background: url('/wp-content/uploads/twitter.gif') no-repeat left 50%;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0.3em 0 0 -0.7em;
    padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
}

ul.follow-background li.blacksquareicon {
    list-style:none outside !important;
    background: url('/wp-content/uploads/black-square-16x16.png') no-repeat left 50%;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0.3em 0 0 -0.6em;
    padding: 0 0 0 1.6em;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>Connect with us through our social media accounts.</p>
    <ul class="follow-background">
        <li class="facebookicon"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/baeeorg" rel="nofollow">Facebook</a></li>
        <li class="twittericon"><a href="https://twitter.com/BaeeArtists" rel="nofollow">Twitter</a></li>
        <li class="blacksquareicon"><a href="/news/">News Announcements (subscribe to get our latest posts)</a> and ensure you know about all our events.</li>
    </ul>
```

These work fine as long as the list item text doesn't wrap. The last line wraps and the image bullet drops down and sits between the two wrapped lines. I'd like it to sit next to the top line.

How do I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using percentage as the vertical background position (`50%`), set a fixed background position - `6px`.

*btw - you can compact the CSS by assigning most properties to a base list item class (`.follow`) instead of repeating them for each list item.*

```css
body {
  width: 400px;
}

.follow {
  list-style: none outside;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: no-repeat left 6px; /** fixed vertical position **/
  margin: 0.3em 0 0 -0.7em;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
}

.follow.facebookicon {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/16/16?1');
}

.follow.twittericon {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/16/16?2');
}

.follow.blacksquareicon {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/16/16?3');
  margin-left: -0.6em;
  padding-left: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="follow-background">
  <li class="follow facebookicon"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/baeeorg" rel="nofollow">Facebook</a></li>
  <li class="follow twittericon"><a href="https://twitter.com/BaeeArtists" rel="nofollow">Twitter</a></li>
  <li class="follow blacksquareicon"><a href="/news/">News Announcements (subscribe to get our latest posts)</a> and ensure you know about all our events.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That works! I had to add  !important to the `list-style: none outside;` to get rid of the bullets that still showed in WordPress 4.8.1. After that--perfect. Thank you and thanks for showing me how to compact the CSS.