# How do I keep the list item text from starting on top of the background image bullet?

Tags: html, css, background-image, bulletedlist

I need some help to figure out how to get the list item text to not start on top of the background image bullet. Here is my code:

```
ul.follow-background {
    list-style: none outside;
    margin: 0 0 0 0.6em;
    padding: 0 0 0 0.6em;
}

.follow {
    list-style: none outside !important;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: no-repeat left 7px; /** fixed vertical position **/
    margin: 0.3em 0 0 -0.6em;
    padding: 0 0 0 1.7em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.follow.blacksquareicon {
    background-image: url('https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/black-square-16x16.png');
}

.follow.facebookicon {
    background-image: url('https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/facebook-icon-16x16.png')
}

.follow.flickricon {
    background-image: url('https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/fluid-flickr-logo-16x16.png');
}

.follow.linkedinicon {
    background-image: url('https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/in.jpg');
}

.follow.pinteresticon {
    background-image: url('https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/pinterest-logo-16x16.png');
}

.follow.rssicon {
    background-image: url('https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/rss.png');
}

.follow.twittericon {
    background-image: url('https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/twitter.gif');
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="follow-background">
    <li class="follow facebookicon"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/baeeorg" rel="nofollow">Facebook</a></li>
    <li class="follow flickricon"><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/baee/" rel="nofollow">Flickr Photo Albums</a></li>
    <li class="follow pinteresticon"><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/baee0196/" rel="nofollow">Pinterest</a></li>
    <li class="follow twittericon"><a href="https://twitter.com/BaeeArtists" rel="nofollow">Twitter</a></li>
    <li class="follow blacksquareicon"><a href="https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/news/" rel="nofollow">News Announcements (subscribe to get our latest posts)</a></li>
</ul>
```

For how this works on my page, see "BAEE's Social Media Connections" section on https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/about-us/#more-12

The code is based on the Answer from @Ori Drori to my question "[How do I keep a background image bullet aligned with the first line of a wrapped list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45902141/how-do-i-keep-a-background-image-bullet-aligned-with-the-first-line-of-a-wrapped/45902404#45902404)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you were right to increase the padding-left value on `.follow` elements. However, this is an issue of specificity -- because another element on the site, `.site-main ul li` is getting a padding value, and `.site-main ul li` is more specific than `.follow`, the padding value is overriding your value for `.follow`.

To get around this, you could update the `.follow` selector to be more specific, i.e. `.follow-background .follow`.

Give this a try and let me know if it doesn't fix your problem, or if my explanation isn't clear. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. See "BAEE's Social Media Connections" section on [link]https://botanical-art.baeecorp.org/about-us/#more-12[/link]